# pywinauto: How to access the application menu, if the application name has spaces in it?

Tags: python-2.7, pywinauto

I have an application called 'Syntext Serna' xml editor. I'm able to open up the application, but when I try to access it's Menu, it's giving me error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
app.dlg.MenuSelect("Document->Open")
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 238, in __getattr__
ctrls = _resolve_control(self.criteria)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 795, 
in _resolve_control
raise e.original_exception
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'dlg' in
'[u'Syntext Serna Free 4.3.0-3001QWidget', u'QWidget',
 u'Syntext Serna Free 4.3.0-3001']'
```

My code:

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application.start(r"C:\Program Files\Syntext\
                                 Serna Free 4.3\bin\serna.exe")
dlg = "Syntext Serna Free 4.3.0-3001"
app.dlg.MenuSelect("Document->Open")
```

I believe the main reason behind this is, the application name has spaces in between. Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dlg name is too far from real dialog caption. You need more close name like this:

```
app.Syntext_Serna_Free_4_3_0_3001.menu_select('Document->Open')
```

Another way to match dialog name with spaces/dashes/etc is using an access by key (such method is also resistant to typos):

```
app['Syntext Serna Free 4.3.0-3001'].menu_select('Document->Open')
```

If you need exact caption equality, just create WindowSpecification object directly (this is most reliable matching method if you have few dialogs/controls with very similar names):

```
app.window(title='Syntext Serna Free 4.3.0-3001').menu_select('Document->Open')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have tried your solution(all 3) but now it is giving me run time error as "There is no menu". I'm even giving a wait of 5 secs before trying to access the Menu.Any idea ?

Comment: Please post an output of the commands: `app['Syntext Serna Free 4.3.0-3001'].PrintControlIdentifiers()` and `app.Windows_()`.

Comment: There are 2 possible cases: (1) another window contains a menu, (2) menu bar is not compatible with pywinauto (like Windows Forms dockable menu bar) because your dialog is not an immediate owner/parent of the menu.

Comment: The output of the commands you mentioned is almost blank. It is only "Control identifiers:". Ignore the quotes in output. I think your second guess is right i.e. menu bar is not compatible!!

Comment: OK, what about `PrintControlIdentifiers()` for `app['Syntext Serna Free 4.3.0-        3001QWidget']` and `app['QWidget']`?

Comment: No, it's still the same output.

Comment: After further research I found that, my application is a QT application, so 'pywinauto' won't work here.Hence I have to use 'pytest' for this purpose.

Comment: That's interesting toolkit. Thank you! It seems pytest-qt plugin can interact with QT GUI interface across processes. Plugging pywinauto in to pytest is a quite interesting task as well.